# Confusion on dimensions of basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> The space $\mathbb{R}^n$ has dimension $n$. Every basis for
>   $\mathbb{R}^n$ consists of $n$ vectors. A plane through $0$ in
>   $\mathbb{R}^3$ is two-dimensional, and a line through $0$ is
>   one-dimensional.

Does somone mind explaining these concepts to me? I don't see why having a plane or line through 0 decreases the dimension of the space by 1. Also, why does every basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ consists of $n$ vectors?

Comment: "decreases the dimension of **the space**""  of what space?  $\Bbb R^3$ is three dimensional, regardless of whether or not you have planes or lines going through the origin.  The **plane itself** is two-dimensional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A line through $0$ can be thought of as all scalar multiples of a given (nonzero) direction vector, so that vector (or any nonzero multiple of it) constitutes a basis for the line. Given such a specific vector $v$, every other point $x$ on the line can be written uniquely in the form $x=\alpha v$ for some scalar $\alpha$.

Likewise, a plane through $0$ is determined by two nonparallel lines through $0$, so by two nonparallel vectors $u$ and $v$ through $0$. Every point $x$ in this plane can be written uniquely  in the form $x=\alpha u+\beta v$ for some scalars $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

This is independent of the dimension of the surrounding space.

Answer (score 1):

1. *The space $\mathbb{R}^n$ has $n$ dimensions*

The canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $B = \{\vec{e}_1,\dots,\vec{e}_n\}$ where $\vec{e}_i := (0, \dots, \underbrace{1}_{i\text{-th element}}, \dots,0)$ and $\#B = n = $'number of elements in $B$' $= \dim(\mathbb{R}^n)$,  for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

2. *Every base for $\mathbb{R}^n$ consists of $n$ vectors*

The number of vectors of the basis $B$ above stated is $n$. Suppose that there is another base $C$ with one vector less. Then it is not a base because we can find a vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that this vector is not a linear combination of vectors in $C$.

3. *A plane through $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is two-dimensional*

A plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a two-dimensional space. Every point in the plane can be described by a linear combination of two vectors that lie in the plane. This is not just for a plane that passes through the $(0,0,0)$ but it is correct for all planes in the space $\mathbb{R}^3$. This is the definition of a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$

4. *A line through $0$ is one-dimensional*

Every line is one-dimensional because you need just one vector and multiples of this vector in space to create all line. Same as the item 3.

---

The dimension of the space does not decreases if a plane pass through the zero, the plane has two-dimensions and the dimensions are related to a basis of the space. I suggest that you should learn about a basis of a vector space and this questions will be much more simplified.  See those questions of math.SE: [vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1937464/in-linear-algebra-what-is-a-vector/1937758#1937758), [basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2195513/what-exactly-is-a-basis-in-linear-algebra/2195546#2195546), [more vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1396798/what-is-mean-by-basis-of-a-vector-space?rq=1)

See also this other: [Why study linear algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256682/why-study-linear-algebra/256695#256695), [What is the difference between a point and a vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/645672/what-is-the-difference-between-a-point-and-a-vector/645827#645827) , [Is linear algebra laying the foundation for something important?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1696686/is-linear-algebra-laying-the-foundation-for-something-important/1696691#1696691) 
, [Where to start learning Linear Algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4335/where-to-start-learning-linear-algebra/4341#4341).